# ios VLC how to convert a frame of video streaming to images

Tags: ios, image, vlc

ow I have a period of video streaming, video of the first frame, name is IDR frame. VLC how to convert a frame of video streaming to images.

Answer (score 0):

There is inbuilt class avaliable in iOS to fetch any frame from video : AVAssetImageGenerator. Please check refrenece document of this class [AVAssetImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/index.html)